# python requests.post data without value don't work

Tags: python, python-requests

how can i post only key of form data to a server like the site itself?

[image: http_post_text_or_only_key_of_dict]

```
In [1]: from requests import Request

In [2]: req = Request('POST', 'http://www.google.com', data={'json':''}).prepare()

In [3]: req.headers, req.body
Out[3]:
({'Content-Length': '5', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
 'json=')

In [4]: req = Request('POST', 'http://www.google.com', data={'json':None}).prepare()

In [5]: req.headers, req.body
Out[5]: ({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, '')
```

the 'Content-Length' can't equal length of key, like 4.
and, how can i make the body equal 'json' ? thx all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests):

> There are times that you may want to send data that is not form-encoded. If you pass in a `string` instead of a `dict`, that data will be posted directly.

In your case, that means doing this:

```
req = Request('POST', 'http://www.google.com', data='json').prepare()
```

Comment: What if you have data that's part dictionary part valueless string?

Comment: @Olumide That's probably worth a separate question. Make sure you give a specific example of the data you're sending and exactly what the output over the wire should look like.

Comment: Done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64829563/python-request-containing-parameters-that-have-values-and-parameters-that-do-not